# Can code read/compute for differences in Pivot Table data?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hi Stack Overflow Hivemind....I could use your help.

I do weekly reporting on sales for a couple clients, and do analysis on the week to week differences in growth with pivot tables. That's basically a lot of manually verifying and what not. I was wondering....is there a way to write code (whether vba or python or sql or whatever have you), that could possibly read the data for me and end up computing what the ups and downs are between the week (this week to last, etc)?

Ie, tell me the difference between this week to the week before, and tell me only the positive movements, but for some points still tell me whether it's up or down regardless. If that doesn't make sense, I'll try to re-explain.

tldr-Can i write code that will analyze performances between weeks for pivot tables, and that will compute for me what the ups and downs are? (By overall amounts, and then what those percentage increases are, etc)?

Comment: Isn't there an option to calculate difference/percentage?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.